# Conditional compilation: #[cfg(foo)] vs #[cfg(feature = "foo")]

Tags: rust

AFAIK, `#[cfg(foo)]` can be activated with `rustc --cfg foo` or with `rustflags = "--cfg foo"` in `.cargo/config.toml`

and `#[cfg(feature="foo")]` is enabled with `cargo build -F foo`

Both seem to achieve conditional compilation, but which one is the correct method?

Comment: Features can also be activated from `Cargo.toml` with `features = ["foo"]`, so if you wish to provide such opportunity use features

Comment: Yes thank you. That relates to "optional dependencies". My question concerns "conditional compilation".

Comment: @exlinx they're both conditional compilation, [as documented](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/conditional-compilation.html#set-configuration-options) `feature` is what [cargo conventionally use for crate-level conditional compilation features](https://doc.rust-lang.org/cargo/reference/features.html), that doesn't have to be optional dependencies e.g. [`tower-http` defines 21 features, less than half of which have an optional dependency component](https://github.com/tower-rs/tower-http/blob/master/tower-http/Cargo.toml#L83-L103).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll most likely want to use features. They can be turned on and off on a per crate basis. That also means that dependants can disable parts of your code that they don't need using features, which is how a lot of features work.

Take axum as an example, which hides something like Cookies behind a `cookies` feature, since not every project that uses axum will want or need to use cookies.

The `--cfg` rustflag on the other hand is more useful if you want to enable or disable code for an entire workspace (or project) and don't really plan on disabling these on a per crate basis. I have most often seen these flags used by projects that have custom build systems (for example AeroOS, which uses the `--cfg` flag to enable or disable 5-Level paging).

Also see @Masklinn comment